# Update navigation based on another ID on page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to match the class on a navigation list item and the current div id.

html on the *Blyfield* page:

```
    <ul>
        <li class="Blyfield"><a href="#">Name Blyfield</a> </li>
        <li class="Britton"><a href="#">Name Britton</a> </li>
        <li class="Cottrell"><a href="#">Name Cottrell</a> </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="Blyfield" class="artist_intro">
        content
    </div>
```

I'm trying to add `.active` to the `li.Blyfield` by checking if on this page the div id = `#Blyfield`

Jquery

```
var bodyID = $(".artist_intro").attr("id");


  if ( $(".artist li").hasClass('bodyID') ) {
  $(this).addClass('active')};
```

My jquery doesn't seem to work, am I using hasClass properly?

Comment: What is the question here ?Can u explain what is that you exactly need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple answer. You need to use `each` function to check all the `li` fields.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var bodyID = $(".artist_intro").attr("id");

 $(".artist li").each(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass(bodyID)) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
   }
 });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/6xnenkp3/)

Comment: Thank you. Correct, I forgot the for each, and few other syntax errors. But I was almost there, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if ($("#Blyfield").length > 0){
    $('li.Blyfield').addClass('active');
  } 
});
```

http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/check-if-an-element-exists-using-jquery/

To get it work dynamicly, just add a unique class to your Blyfield div:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="Blyfield"><a href="#">Name Blyfield</a> </li>
    <li class="Britton"><a href="#">Name Britton</a> </li>
    <li class="Cottrell"><a href="#">Name Cottrell</a> </li>
</ul>

<div id="Blyfield" class="uniqueClass artist_intro">
    content
</div>
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  //check if there is a content-div
  if ($(".uniqueClass").length > 0){
    //Get the ID of the content-div = Class of the active li
    var id = $('.uniqueClass').attr('id');
    //addClass to li-element
    $('li.'+id).addClass('active');
  } 
});
```

Comment: yes but what if the names are dynamic, how would I use this for Britton or Cottrell?

Comment: Have a look at my edit. You have to add the `uniqueClass` class to #Britton and #Cottrell div and make sure they are on different pages.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I will edit HTML to :

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="Blyfield"><a href="#">Name Blyfield</a> </li>
    <li class="Britton"><a href="#">Name Britton</a> </li>
    <li class="Cottrell"><a href="#">Name Cottrell</a> </li>
</ul>

<div id="Blyfield" class="in-nav artist_intro" data-navitem="Blyfield">
    content
</div>
```

Then write jQuery code:

```
if( $('.in-nav').length > 0 ){
    var navClass = $('.in-nav').data('navitem');
    $('.nav').find('.'+navClass).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this is better way to highlight a nav item, but I'd like to limit changes to the jQuery as much as possible to learn where I could improve. Thank you for your time!